# Saving an excel sheet opened with join(dir_path..) in python

Tags: python, excel

Given below is my code:

```
from os.path import join
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
import xlwt


def Trend():
    fname = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))),'Data Files', 'Processed Data', 'TrendAnalysis.xls')

    # Open the workbook

    book = open_workbook(fname, formatting_info=True)
    wb = copy(book) # a writable copy (I can't read values out of this, only write to it)
    total=0.
    style = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 1, name Calibri')
    style1 = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Calibri')
    for i in range(2,25):

        if(i==1):
            pass
        else:        
            sheet = book.sheet_by_index(i)
            w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(i) # the sheet to write to within the writable copy

            cols = sheet.ncols   # Number of columns
            rows = sheet.nrows   # Number of rows

            for column in range(1,cols):

                for row in range(1,rows):
                    if(sheet.cell(row,column).value == '-'):
                        pass

                    else:

                        total=total+sheet.cell(row,column).value
                w_sheet.write(row+1, column, total, style1)
                total=0
            w_sheet.write(row+1,0, 'TOTAL', style)
            i=i+1

    s=book.sheet_by_index(0)
    w = wb.get_sheet(0)
    cols = s.ncols   # Number of columns
    rows = s.nrows   # Number of rows
    for row in range(1,rows):
        if(s.cell(row,0).value== "ISU-GOV Domestic"):
            for column in range(0,3):
                a=s.cell(row,column).value
                b=s.cell(21,column).value
                w.write(21,column,a)
                w.write(row,column,b)
        elif(s.cell(row,0).value== "ISU-GOV Overseas"):
            for column in range(0,3):
                a=s.cell(row,column).value
                b=s.cell(23,column).value
                w.write(row,column,b)
                w.write(23,column,a)
        elif(s.cell(row,0).value== "ISU-MFG (TML)"):
            for column in range(0,3):
                a=s.cell(row,column).value
                w.write(24,column,a)
                b=s.cell(20,column).value
                w.write(12,column,b)
        elif(s.cell(row,0).value== "NGM-INDIA"):
            for column in range(0,3):
                a=s.cell(row,column).value
                w.write(25,column,a)

        else:
            c=s.cell(row,0).value
            w.write(row, 0, c)

    for column in range(1,cols):

        for row in range(1,20):
            if(s.cell(row,column).value == '-'):
                pass

            else:

                total=total+s.cell(row,column).value
        w.write(20, column, total, style1)
        total=0
    w.write(20,0, 'SUB TOTAL', style)

    for column in range(1,cols):

        for row in range(20,rows):
            if(s.cell(row,column).value == '-'):
                pass

            else:

                total=total+s.cell(row,column).value
        w.write(26, column, total, style1)
        total=0
    w.write(26,0, 'SUB TOTAL', style)

    for column in range(1,cols):

        for row in range(1,rows):
            if(s.cell(row,column).value == '-'):
                pass

            else:

                total=total+s.cell(row,column).value
        w.write(27, column, total, style1)
        total=0
    w.write(27,0, 'GRAND TOTAL', style)    




    wb.save('fname')
```

The changes made to the excel file do not get reflected. The compilation doesnt give an errors ,yet none of these changes have been made on that excel sheet. Could you please help me sort the issue .?

Answer (score 0):

The line in your program that says:

```
wb.save('fname')
```

will save to a file named 'fname'.

You want to use your fname variable, rather than the literal string 'fname', so that line should read:

```
wb.save(fname)
```